# Index with æ ø and å

Tags: indexing, scandinavian-letters

I Have createt a minimal example of my document. I want to create a Index, but the letters Æ, Ø and Å it considered as symbols instead of letters as shown:
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{imakeidx}
 \makeindex[columns=3, title=Index, intoc,options=-s Index.ist]
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\index{Børge}
\index{Børge!Hej med dig}
\index{Børge!Hey with you}
\index{A}
\index{hej}
\index{Cykel}
\index{wow}
\index{hn}
\index{$\sigma$}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\index{hesj}
\index{AA}
\index{Åse}
\index{æse}
\index{øse}
\index{Yrsa}
\index{Yrsa!Carla}
\index{hejsas}
\index{heASDASDj}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The ist file I'm uisng called Index.ist is this:

```
 headings_flag 1
 heading_prefix "\\textbf\{\\color\{black\}"
heading_prefix "\n\\centering\\large\\sffamily\\textbf{\\color\{black\}}%
\\noindent\\textbf{"heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"
heading_suffix "\}\\nopagebreak\n"
item_0 "\n \\item \\small \\color\{black\}"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

Any Idea how to solve this

Comment: MakeIndex does not deal with other alphabets (like Danish or Swedish); you have to use Xindy for that.

Comment: How do I do that. Is it just to load the package Xindy ?

Comment: `xindy` isn't a package but the processor; you use it instead og the `makeindex` command. But as you use the `imakeidx`-package you can instruct it to call `xindy` for you -- it is described quite well in it's manual.

Comment: `xindy` is the way to go for a complete index in, say, Danish. But if you are writing a document in English with only a few words with foreign letters, a quick fix would be to fix the sorting for these few manually e.g. `\index{Azse@Åse}`

Answer (score 6):

[![
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnb7F.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnb7F.png)xindy is more than just a package, you have to run it. From the CTAN short description:

> Xindy can be used to pro­cess in­dexes for doc­u­ments marked up us­ing (LA)TEX, Nroff fam­ily and SGML-based lan­guages.

A workaround I used years ago when I wasn't using utf-8 is to divide your index entry in two parts, one with the ansii entry that will be alphabetically sorted, the second with what will be printed. For instance, in French or Polish

```
 \index{Conde-sur-l'Escaut@Cond\'e-sur-l'Escaut}
 \index{Dazbrowa Gornicza@D\cog abrowa G\'ornicza}
```

You can see on the second entry that I added a "z" after "Da" since ą should be sorted after az according to polish alphabet. D\cog abrowa G\'ornicza will be printed as Dąbrowa Górnicza.

This should work with makeindex, and might be worth trying if your index is short and you don't have time to learn xindy. Very (too?) old-fashioned indeed…

Answer (score 5):

You have to use Xindy as the index processor. How to make it work with symbols is something I can't understand, though. `:-(`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[
  columns=3,
  title=Index,
  intoc,
  program=truexindy,
  options=-M texindy -C utf8 -L danish,
]
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
Text
\index{Børge}
\index{Børge!Hej med dig}
\index{Børge!Hey with you}
\index{A}
\index{hej}
\index{Cykel}
\index{wow}
\index{hn}
\index{sigma@$\sigma$}

\chapter{Second chapter}
text
\index{hesj}
\index{AA}
\index{Åse}
\index{æse}
\index{øse}
\index{Yrsa}
\index{Yrsa!Carla}
\index{hejsas}
\index{heASDASDj}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Compile with the `-shell-escape` option, as explained in the manual. For changing the index formatting you need to use Xindy methods.

This is the result; I can see a wrong entry for `æse`, but that's a problem with Xindy.

Here's a hack for getting it to work:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[
  columns=3,
  title=Index,
  intoc,
  program=truexindy,
  options=-M texindy -C utf8 -L danish,
]

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\index[2][\imki@jobname]{%
    \@bsphack
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\@index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}}\x
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
Text
\index{Børge}
\index{Børge!Hej med dig}
\index{Børge!Hey with you}
\index{A}
\index{hej}
\index{Cykel}
\index{wow}
\index{hn}
\index{sigma@$\sigma$}

\chapter{Second chapter}
text
\index{hesj}
\index{AA}
\index{Åse}
\index{æse}
\index{øse}
\index{Yrsa}
\index{Yrsa!Carla}
\index{hejsas}
\index{heASDASDj}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not really the best, though. Possibly a better sanitization method is necessary. Of course, using a Unicode engine should solve all problems.

Comment: In this context, what do you mean by symbols?

Comment: @daleif The `\sigma`, for instance.

Comment: Yeah, xindy ignores the ``\``

Comment: @daleif And also doesn't honor `\ae`, for instance. It's able to see that `\r A` is an A, but it doesn't sort correctly anyway. There *should* be a good method. :(

Comment: I think I have a config file for that somewhere. Will see on Monday. It is sad that many of these things does not get fixed. Primarily because hardly anyone knows how xindy works. See see the hassle that had to be done to get it to work with utf8

Comment: what is the problem you note about æse? it is sorted correctly. AA is debatable, but AA or normally Aa is just a different spelling for Å, for example my town changed its spelling a few years ago, from Århus to Aarhus. The university where I work have been using Aarhus since it was founded (founded before the Å started being used).

Comment: @daleif With the hack it's sorted correctly; with the default set up it isn't.

Comment: I just deleted all that and used standard `makeidx` plus `texindy -L danish -C utf8`, it sorted æse correctly. Cannot handle `\index{\ae se}` though, but that was not in you MWE.

Comment: @daleif It's a problem with Xindy, then: if I run `texindy -L danish -C utf8`, the sorting is good; if I run `xindy -M texindy -L danish -C utf8`, it's bad. `:(`

Comment: can't `imakeidx` use `texindy`? It is probably something we need Joachim to look at it. I wasn't aware of the `\ae se` sorting problem. At least with `texindy` `\ae` is ignored while sorting.