# xindex - sorting local characters (ÆØÅæøå)

Tags: indexing, sorting, extended-characters, xindex

I have tried to use the new [xindex](https://ctan.org/pkg/xindex) indexing package on a Norwegian manuscript. I modified the `xindex-cfg-common.lua` as indicated in the documentation, and made a character matrix with some minor changes. Adding Norwegian to the `folium{}` also works, which is invoked by `-l no`.

The new configuration file is named `xindex-norsk.lua`, is loaded with the commands:

```
\usepackage[imakeidx]{xindex}
\makeindex[options=-c norsk -l no]
```

It works to some extent, but it will not sort `ÆØÅæøå` in correct order, and will not recognize that `æøå` is the lower case of `ÆØÅ`.

I have tested code from other configuration files without any luck, since I have no knowledge of Lua (or any other programming language). For example, the sorting routine from the `xindex-yannis.lua` resulted in no output at all when I copied it to my `xindex-norsk.lua` file.

The output when using my `xindex-norsk.lua` is like this:

[image]

The upper-/lowercase issue can be ‘fixed’ by forcing sort order

```
åkerhøne\index{Åkerhøne@åkerhøne}
```

but the wrong sorting of the character means lot of manual editing of the .idx-file.

Is there any easy way to fix this?

Complete .cfg and MWE:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
--         FILE:  xindex-norsk.lua
--  DESCRIPTION:  configuration file for xindex.lua
-- REQUIREMENTS:  
--       AUTHOR:  Herbert Voß
--     MODIFIED:  Sveinung Heggen (2020-01-02)
--      LICENSE:  LPPL1.3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

if not modules then modules = { } end modules ['xindex-cfg'] = {
      version = 0.20,
      comment = "configuration to xindex.lua",
       author = "Herbert Voss",
    copyright = "Herbert Voss",
      license = "LPPL 1.3"
}

escape_chars = { -- by default " is the escape char
  {'""', "\\escapedquote",      '\"{}' },
  {'"@', "\\escapedat",         "@"    },
  {'"|', "\\escapedvert",       "|"    },
  {'"!', "\\escapedexcl",       "!"    },
  {'"(', "\\escapedparenleft",  "("   },
  {'")', "\\escapedparenright", ")"  }
}

itemPageDelimiter = ","     -- Hello, 14
compressPages     = true    -- something like 12--15, instead of 12,13,14,15. the |( ... |) syntax is still valid
fCompress         = true    -- 3f -> page 3, 4 and 3ff -> page 3, 4, 5
minCompress       = 3       -- 14--17 or 
numericPage       = true    -- for non-numerical page numbers, like "VI-17"
sublabels         = {"", "---\\,", "--\\,", "-\\,"} -- for the (sub(sub(sub-items  first one is for item
pageNoPrefixDel   = ""     -- a delimiter for page numbers like "VI-17"
indexOpening      = ""     -- commands after \begin{theindex}
rangeSymbol       = "--"
idxnewletter      = "\\textbf"  -- Only valid if -n is not set

folium = { 
  de = {"f.", "ff."},
  en = {"f.", "ff."},
  fr = {"\\,sq","\\,sqq"},
  no = {"\\,f.","\\,ff."},
} 


--[[
    Each character's position in this array-like table determines its 'priority'.
    Several characters in the same slot have the same 'priority'.
]]

alphabet_lower = { --   for sorting
    { ' ' },  -- only for internal tests
    { 'a', 'á', 'à', },
    { 'b' },
    { 'c', 'ç' },
    { 'd' },
    { 'e', 'é', 'è', 'ë', 'ê' },
    { 'f' },
    { 'g' },
    { 'h' },
    { 'i', 'í', 'ì', 'î', 'ï' },
    { 'j' },
    { 'k' },
    { 'l' },
    { 'm' },
    { 'n', 'ñ' },
    { 'o', 'ó', 'ò', 'ô' },
    { 'p' },
    { 'q' },
    { 'r' },
    { 's', 'š', 'ß' },
    { 't' },
    { 'u', 'ú', 'ù', 'û' },
    { 'v' },
    { 'w' },
    { 'x' },
    { 'y', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'ü' },
    { 'z', 'ž' },
    { 'æ', 'œ', 'ä' },
    { 'ø', 'ö' },
    { 'å' }
}
alphabet_upper = { -- for sorting
    { ' ' },
    { 'A', 'Á', 'À', 'Â'},
    { 'B' },
    { 'C', 'Ç' },
    { 'D' },
    { 'E', 'È', 'É', 'Ë', 'Ê' },
    { 'F' },
    { 'G' },
    { 'H' },
    { 'I', 'Í', 'Ì', 'Ï', 'Î' },
    { 'J' },
    { 'K' },
    { 'L' },
    { 'M' },
    { 'N', 'Ñ' },
    { 'O', 'Ó', 'Ò', 'Ô' },
    { 'P' },
    { 'Q' },
    { 'R' },
    { 'S', 'Š' },
    { 'T' },
    { 'U', 'Ú', 'Ù', 'Û' },
    { 'V' },
    { 'W' },
    { 'X' },
    { 'Y', 'Ý', 'Ÿ', 'Ü' },
    { 'Z', 'Ž' },
    { 'Æ', 'Œ', 'Ä' },
    { 'Ø', 'Ö' },
    { 'Å' }
}
```

Test file for indexed words (MWE):

```
\documentclass[norsk]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[imakeidx]{xindex}
\makeindex[options=-c norsk -l no]

\begin{document}

Anemone\index{Anemone|(}
Anemone\index{Anemone}
Anemone\index{Anemone}

Àctomere\index{Àctomere}
Bartëloemeus\index{Bartëloemeus}
Bartelomeus\index{Bartelomeus}
Cicero\index{Cicero}
Citroën\index{Citroën}
Delta\index{Delta}
Epsilon\index{Epsilon}
Forfatter\index{Forfatter}

For\index{For}
Fôr\index{Fôr}
Får\index{Får}
Färdsel\index{Färdsel}
Færøyene\index{Færøyene}
Anemone\index{Anemone}
Anemone\index{Anemone}

Gavepakker\index{Gavepakker}
Grisgrendt\index{Grisgrendt}
Göteborg\index{Göteborg}
Heggen\index{Heggen}
Havørn\index{Havørn}
Havtor\index{Havtor}
Indigo\index{Indigo}
Înderer\index{Înderer}
Interesse\index{Interesse}
Joker\index{Joker}
Jôkum\index{Jôkum}
Jökullen\index{Jökullen}
København\index{København}
Kjære\index{Kjære}
Kjøre\index{Kjøre}
Kjole\index{Kjole}
Kåre\index{Kåre}
Lam\index{Lam}
Lammeull\index{Lammeull}
Mammakjole\index{Mammakjole}
Mamelukk\index{Mamelukk}
Mehe\index{Mehe}
Noen\index{Noen}
Neon\index{Neon}
Oppetid\index{Oppetid}
Oppenheim\index{Oppenheim}
Ôskardir\index{Ôskardir}
Pappenheimer\index{Pappenheimer}
Prada\index{Prada}
Praha\index{Praha}
Quisling\index{Quisling}
Quest\index{Quest}
Raske\index{Raske}
Raska\index{Raska}
Ramböll\index{Ramböll}
Sistemann\index{Sistemann}
Sitroner\index{Sitroner}
Utenpå\index{Utenpå}
Überall\index{Überall}
Varig\index{Varig}
Verdipapir\index{Verdipapir}
Wikipedia\index{Wikipedia}
Xindy\index{Xindy}
Xindex\index{Xindex}
Xanadu\index{Xanadu}
Ytterplagg\index{Ytterplagg}
Ynkelig\index{Ynkelig}
Zackariassen\index{Zackariassen}
Zambia\index{Zambia}
Ærfugl\index{Ærfugl}
Ærekjær\index{Ærekjær}
Øredøvende\index{Øredøvende}
Øvelse\index{Øvelse}
Äckligt\index{Äckligt}
Åkerhøne\index{Åkerhøne}
Åkerhane\index{Åkerhane}

\newpage
Anemone\index{Anemone}
Anemone\index{Anemone|)}

anemone\index{anemone}
àctomere\index{àctomere}
bartëloemeus\index{bartëloemeus}
bartelomeus\index{bartelomeus}
cicero\index{cicero}
citroën\index{citroën}
delta\index{delta}
epsilon\index{epsilon}
forfatter\index{forfatter}
fôr\index{fôr}
for\index{for}
får\index{får}
färdsel\index{färdsel}
færøyene\index{færøyene}
gavepakker\index{gavepakker}
grisgrendt\index{grisgrendt}
göteborger\index{göteborger}
heggen\index{heggen}
havørn\index{havørn}
havtor\index{havtor}
indigo\index{indigo}
înderer\index{înderer}
interesse\index{interesse}
joker\index{joker}
jôkum\index{jôkum}
jökullen\index{jökullen}
københavn\index{københavn}
kjære\index{kjære}
kjøre\index{kjøre}
kjole\index{kjole}
lam\index{lam}
lammeull\index{lammeull}
mammakjole\index{mammakjole}
mamelukk\index{mamelukk}
mehe\index{mehe}
noen\index{noen}
neon\index{neon}
oppetid\index{oppetid}
oppenheim\index{oppenheim}
ôskardir\index{ôskardir}
pappenheimer\index{pappenheimer}
prada\index{prada}
praha\index{praha}
quisling\index{quisling}
quest\index{quest}
raske\index{raske}
raska\index{raska}
ramböll\index{ramböll}
sistemann\index{sistemann}
sitroner\index{sitroner}
utenpå\index{utenpå}
überall\index{überall}
varig\index{varig}
verdipapir\index{verdipapir}
wikipedia\index{wikipedia}
xindy\index{xindy}
xindex\index{xindex}
xanadu\index{xanadu}
ytterplagg\index{ytterplagg}
ynkelig\index{ynkelig}
zackariassen\index{zackariassen}
zambia\index{zambia}
ærfugl\index{ærfugl}
ærekjær\index{ærekjær}
øredøvende\index{øredøvende}
øvelse\index{øvelse}
äckligt\index{äckligt}
åkerhøne\index{Åkerhøne@åkerhøne}
åkerhane\index{åkerhane}


\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could try the dirty trick I used long ago for my PHD https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272156/index-with-%C3%A6-%C3%B8-and-%C3%A5/272158#272158

Comment: @sztruks I have investigated that, i could search and replace all Æ or æ with a sorting key `Zz1`, all Ø or ø with `Zz2` etc., i.e (`\index{Zz1verby@Øverby}`) etc. Then you can use `makeindx` directly. But it was this type of hacking I hoped to avoid by using `xindex`.

Comment: Is it the normal behaviour that ÆÅ are _not_ sorted under A and Ø _not_ under O?

Comment: @user187802 ÆØÅ is independent letters as is the last three letters in the Norwegian alphabet and is always sorted in that order. We have 29 letters. The sorting order is ÆæØøÅå (capital letters first). Umlauts with the same sound are normally sorted together: Ä -> Æ, Ö -> Ø and Ü -> Y. They are not ordinary letter in Norwegian, but are used in names, brands etc.

Comment: I see. The problem is that Lua must return the lowercase for ÆØÅ. I'll see if Michals new modul will help or if I should handle these special characters individually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just created a new package that adds support for the [Unicode collation algorithm](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) for LuaTeX - [Lua-UCA](https://github.com/michal-h21/lua-uca). I've already added support for few languages, like Czech, German or Norwegian. We can use it instead of `Xindex` built in sorting mechanism.

Try the following version of `xindex-norsk.lua`:

```lua
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
--         FILE:  xindex-norsk.lua
--  DESCRIPTION:  configuration file for xindex.lua
-- REQUIREMENTS:  
--       AUTHOR:  Herbert Voß
--     MODIFIED:  Sveinung Heggen (2020-01-02)
--      LICENSE:  LPPL1.3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

if not modules then modules = { } end modules ['xindex-cfg'] = {
      version = 0.20,
      comment = "configuration to xindex.lua",
       author = "Herbert Voss",
    copyright = "Herbert Voss",
      license = "LPPL 1.3"
}

local ducet = require "lua-uca.lua-uca-ducet"
local collator = require "lua-uca.lua-uca-collator"
local languages = require "lua-uca.lua-uca-languages"
local collator_obj = collator.new(ducet)

local language = "en" -- default language
-- language specified on the command line doesn't seem to be available
-- in the config file, so we just try to find it ourselves
for i, a in ipairs(arg) do
  if a == "-l" or a=="--language" then
    language = arg[i+1]
    break
  end
end

if languages[language] then
  print("[Lua-UCA] Loading language: " .. language)
  collator_obj = languages[language](collator_obj)
end

local upper = unicode.utf8.upper


escape_chars = { -- by default " is the escape char
  {'""', "\\escapedquote",      '\"{}' },
  {'"@', "\\escapedat",         "@"    },
  {'"|', "\\escapedvert",       "|"    },
  {'"!', "\\escapedexcl",       "!"    },
  {'"(', "\\escapedparenleft",  "("   },
  {'")', "\\escapedparenright", ")"  }
}

itemPageDelimiter = ","     -- Hello, 14
compressPages     = true    -- something like 12--15, instead of 12,13,14,15. the |( ... |) syntax is still valid
fCompress         = true    -- 3f -> page 3, 4 and 3ff -> page 3, 4, 5
minCompress       = 3       -- 14--17 or 
numericPage       = true    -- for non-numerical page numbers, like "VI-17"
sublabels         = {"", "---\\,", "--\\,", "-\\,"} -- for the (sub(sub(sub-items  first one is for item
pageNoPrefixDel   = ""     -- a delimiter for page numbers like "VI-17"
indexOpening      = ""     -- commands after \begin{theindex}
rangeSymbol       = "--"
idxnewletter      = "\\textbf"  -- Only valid if -n is not set

folium = { 
  de = {"f.", "ff."},
  en = {"f.", "ff."},
  fr = {"\\,sq","\\,sqq"},
  no = {"\\,f.","\\,ff."},
} 

function UTFCompare(a,b)
  local A = a["SortKey"]
  local B = b["SortKey"]
  return collator_obj:compare_strings(A,B)
end

function SORTendhook(list)
  -- get the headers for letter groups
  for k,v in ipairs(list) do 
    -- the collator:get_lowest_char will return character on the given
    -- position. It will be lowercase and without accents.
    local codepoints = collator_obj:string_to_codepoints(v.Entry)
    local codes = collator_obj:get_lowest_char(codepoints, 1)
    local sort_char = utf8.char(table.unpack(codes))
    v.sortChar = upper(sort_char) -- use unicode.utf8.upper to make the char uppercase
  end
  return list
end

--[[
    Each character's position in this array-like table determines its 'priority'.
    Several characters in the same slot have the same 'priority'.
]]

alphabet_lower = { --   for sorting
    { ' ' },  -- only for internal tests
    { 'a', 'á', 'à', },
    { 'b' },
    { 'c', 'ç' },
    { 'd' },
    { 'e', 'é', 'è', 'ë', 'ê' },
    { 'f' },
    { 'g' },
    { 'h' },
    { 'i', 'í', 'ì', 'î', 'ï' },
    { 'j' },
    { 'k' },
    { 'l' },
    { 'm' },
    { 'n', 'ñ' },
    { 'o', 'ó', 'ò', 'ô' },
    { 'p' },
    { 'q' },
    { 'r' },
    { 's', 'š', 'ß' },
    { 't' },
    { 'u', 'ú', 'ù', 'û' },
    { 'v' },
    { 'w' },
    { 'x' },
    { 'y', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'ü' },
    { 'z', 'ž' },
    { 'æ', 'œ', 'ä' },
    { 'ø', 'ö' },
    { 'å' }
}
alphabet_upper = { -- for sorting
    { ' ' },
    { 'A', 'Á', 'À', 'Â'},
    { 'B' },
    { 'C', 'Ç' },
    { 'D' },
    { 'E', 'È', 'É', 'Ë', 'Ê' },
    { 'F' },
    { 'G' },
    { 'H' },
    { 'I', 'Í', 'Ì', 'Ï', 'Î' },
    { 'J' },
    { 'K' },
    { 'L' },
    { 'M' },
    { 'N', 'Ñ' },
    { 'O', 'Ó', 'Ò', 'Ô' },
    { 'P' },
    { 'Q' },
    { 'R' },
    { 'S', 'Š' },
    { 'T' },
    { 'U', 'Ú', 'Ù', 'Û' },
    { 'V' },
    { 'W' },
    { 'X' },
    { 'Y', 'Ý', 'Ÿ', 'Ü' },
    { 'Z', 'Ž' },
    { 'Æ', 'Œ', 'Ä' },
    { 'Ø', 'Ö' },
    { 'Å' }
}
```

The relevant code is this:

```lua
local ducet = require "lua-uca.lua-uca-ducet"
local collator = require "lua-uca.lua-uca-collator"
local languages = require "lua-uca.lua-uca-languages"
local collator_obj = collator.new(ducet)
local language = "en" -- default language
-- language specified on the command line doesn't seem to be available
-- in the config file, so we just try to find it ourselves
for i, a in ipairs(arg) do
  if a == "-l" or a=="--language" then
    language = arg[i+1]
    break
  end
end

if languages[language] then
  print("[Lua-UCA] Loading language: " .. language)
  collator_obj = languages[language](collator_obj)
end

local upper = unicode.utf8.upper

function UTFCompare(a,b)
  local A = a["SortKey"]
  local B = b["SortKey"]
  return collator_obj:compare_strings(A,B)
end

function SORTendhook(list)
  -- get the headers for letter groups
  for k,v in ipairs(list) do 
    -- the collator:get_lowest_char will return character on the given
    -- position. It will be lowercase and without accents.
    local codepoints = collator_obj:string_to_codepoints(v.Entry)
    local codes = collator_obj:get_lowest_char(codepoints, 1)
    local sort_char = utf8.char(table.unpack(codes))
    v.sortChar = upper(sort_char) -- use unicode.utf8.upper to make the char uppercase
  end
  return list
end
```

It loads the needed  libraries, creates the sorting object and applies the Norwegian rules. The `UTFSort` function is used by `Xindex`. We redefine it to use our sorting function. I've found that sorting works, but there is one problem - the first letters are not handled correctly, so `Xindex` produced separate headings for uppercase and lowercase letters. This is handled in the `SORTendhook` function.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. I will test it later in the evening.

Comment: @Sveinung sure, it is not yet part of TeX Live, it needs to be installed from https://github.com/michal-h21/lua-uca

Comment: @Sveinung does the installation fail? You may need to create the data directory manually and place file [allkeys](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/latest/allkeys.txt) here. It is then necessary to execute command `texlua tools/make_ducet.lua > src/lua-uca/lua-uca-ducet.lua`. The files from `src/lua-uca` directory then need to be copied to the local TEXMF tree, which may need to be created manually.

Comment: There is no "make install" in MikTeX, so I have to try the manual way.

Comment: @Sveinung oh, that's bad. I hope the method from my previous comment works.

Comment: @Sveinung sure. I've updated the Lua-UCA repo with a new configuration file for Xindex and several examples for various languages

Comment: @Sveinung ah, yes :( Serpent is necessary to generate the lookup table. I have it installed using LuaRocks, but it may be not the easiest way for end users, so I've added it to the distribution.

Comment: I can confirm lua-uca now works with the latest update using `xindex-uca.lua` as configuration file.

Comment: @Sveinung that's great! I want to add last major lacking feature - script order reordering and then I will release it to CTAN.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Where do I find your e-mail address?

Answer (score 4):

With the current `xindex` (version 0.23) and

```
xindex -u -l no -c norsk <file>
```

you'll get

[image][image]

**Inserted by Sveinung 4.6.2020**

Sorting order table for Nordic character according to Norwegian rules (including Sami):

```
A   Á   B   C   Č   D   Ð   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   Ŋ   O   P   Q   R   S   Š   T   Ŧ   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   Ž   Æ   Ä   Ø   Ö   Å   Aa  
1   3   5   7   9   11  13  15  17  19  21  23  25  27  29  31  33  35  37  39  41  43  45  47  49  51  53  55  57  59  61  63  65  67  69  71  73  75  75  
a   á   b   c   č   d   đ   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   ŋ   o   p   q   r   s   š   t   ŧ   u   v   w   x   y   z   ž   æ   ä   ø   ö   å   aa  
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38  40  42  44  46  48  50  52  54  56  58  60  62  64  66  68  70  72  74  76  76  

A   1
a   2
Á   3
á   4
B   5
b   6
C   7
c   8
Č   9
č   10
D   11
d   12
Ð   13
đ   14
E   15
e   16
F   17
f   18
G   19
g   20
H   21
h   22
I   23
i   24
J   25
j   26
K   27
k   28
L   29
l   30
M   31
m   32
N   33
n   34
Ŋ   35
ŋ   36
O   37
o   38
P   39
p   40
Q   41
q   42
R   43
r   44
S   45
s   46
Š   47
š   48
T   49
t   50
Ŧ   51
ŧ   52
U   53
u   54
V   55
v   56
W   57
w   58
X   59
x   60
Y   61
y   62
Z   63
z   64
Ž   65
ž   66
Æ   67
æ   68
Ä   69
ä   70
Ø   71
ø   72
Ö   73
ö   74
Å   75
Aa  75
å   76
aa  76
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not correct sorting according to Norwegian (ISO) sorting rules. However, this is the sorting EU try to enforce upon us through the EEA treaty.

Comment: Where can I find the sorting rules for Norwegian text?

Comment: I suppose something like this: A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  Æ  Ø  Å

Comment: I will see if I find the reference in English

Comment: I inserted the table the Norwegian Tax Authority uses at different public sites. Is sorts all Nordic characters according to local standard. However, you have in addition characters which are not in the Norwegian alphabet, like German ü/Û. In addition, som of the characters should be sorted depending on language (German Öö as OE/oe) and AA/aa as AA/aa not as Å/å. Those can be handled by the @-notation  in the indexing (`\index{Aaron@Aaron}`) .

Comment: In german we have two possibilities for `ö->o` or `ö->oe`. One is ISO (DIN) and one is the so-called telefonbook sorting